# Find step to divide sum of two very big ints on equal chunks

Tags: java, math, distance

I have two limits - **start** and **end** which are long values. I need to find **step** to divide distance between **start** and **end** on equal chunks.

So the formula actually is following:

```
(end - start)/1000
```

where 1000 is amount of chunks. The problem comes when start is Long.MIN_VALUE or near to it and end is Long.MAX_VALUE.

Thanks

Comment: If you're just doing this a few times then use `BigInteger`. It's easy and does not suffer from such problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html) instead:

```
BigInteger bigStart = BigInteger.valueOf(start);
BigInteger bigEnd = BigInteger.valueOf(end);
BigInteger bigDiv = BigInteger.valueOf(1000);

BigInteger step = bigEnd.subtract(bigStart).divide(bigDiv);
```